# Checking validity of users and tenants in each request

Tags: authorization, identity, middleware

I am designing a centralized IDP to use for a database-per-tenant application that uses a "tid" (Tenant Id) claim in the access token that the WebAPI uses to create a connection string dynamically.

I have two entities in my IDP, `User` and `Organization`representing the user and the tenant. Both entities have an `IsActive` property in case of either a malicious User or an Organization that hasn't paid. Once a user logs in, it has a `SelectedOrg` property set when they choose from a list of their available tenants in a portal, which is just the GUID of the selected Organization. The "tid" claim's value is set to this when the user clears the portal. There is a join table `UserOrganization` as they have a many-many relationship.

However, the problem is validating all of this in a fast and straightforward way. The main issues arise when

- An Organization is deactivated and some user is still accessing their database.
- A User is deactivated and is still logged in and working.
- A User has access to an Organization revoked while still accessing their database

From what I can think of there seem to be 2 ways to handle those cases. The IDP can validate all of this as part of its normal authorization and log users out if necessary to correct things. On the other hand, you can make sure that you sign out the appropriate Users whenever a User/Organization is deactivated or some access is revoked. Essentially, it is a "net" versus a reactive system.

The first way which I was working on, the IDP would verify in each request that

- The current User corresponding to the request's identity is active.
- The User has access to the Organization based on its `SelectedOrg` (checking if a join table record exists).
- The same Organization from above is active.

The problem with the above method is I feel like adding this database interaction to each request is heavy.

The second way, I would just make sure to add some sort of service that would sign users out and redirect them with an appropriate message if any problematic change occurred. However, this adds a lot of responsibility in the development and a lot more testing is required to ensure all problematic changes are covered.

I am not sure if the second way is just expensive premature optimization, but the first way seems like it would add a fair amount of overhead.

**MY SOLUTION:**
EDIT: My solution was to not use JWTs for authorization. See https://github.com/perustaja/PermissionServerDemo

Comment: What is your app doing? If you’re serving cat videos, then maybe a few minutes delay on the deactivation is fine.

Comment: @Telastyn. It is flight scheduling software (pilots can book flights, simulator time, etc.). Are you suggesting to simply wait for a logout cycle to occur? I did think about that but I suppose I could keep expire timespans on my tokens short. That is an interesting idea.

Comment: Or some eventual consistency cache rather than hitting the DB directly.

Comment: @Telastyn That makes quite a bit of sense, when you say eventual consistency cache would that include, say, the cache-aside pattern?

Comment: Yes. Personally, I tend to favor a simple TTL rather than some eviction strategy.

Comment: What I'm going to do is implement the first method and then add caching to it like you said. I'll definitely benchmark everything before and after. I suppose if even after caching the performance is unacceptable I will need to take a different approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, the number of users affected by such an access-revoking event will be far less than the total number of users in your system.

The easiest option would be to continue allowing those users access until their access token expires and needs to be refreshed.

If that delay is not acceptable to your stakeholders, you could also create an auxiliary table with the usernames of the users that were affected by an access-revoking event. On each request, you can make a query of this table to see if the current user is listed there. If it is, you do a more complete check against the database if the resource they want to access is still allowed. If the user is not listed, you can just continue with accessing the resource, because the user's access rights will not have changed.

The advantage here is that the check against the auxiliary table is presumably much cheaper than the full check against the database, because it is a single, rather small table.

Comment: I scrapped banning Users wholesale so they no longer have an IsActive property. From the feedback here I realized that allowing an unpaid tenant's access to naturally expire is absolutely fine for me. Here, this makes more sense, I just need to figure out the fastest way to store these users. I would like to avoid a db for speed but I need the persistence.